# Prime numbers no loop no recursive

Tags: java, numbers

I have a doubt! It's the same always problem about the Prime numbers!! Is it possible to make it without using loops or recursive methods? Thanks a lot!! I have tried this (works for the first numbers!):

```
public static boolean Prime(int number) {
    Scanner leer = new Scanner(System.in);
    int test1 = number % 2;
    int test2 = number % 3;
    int test3 = number % 5;
    if (number == 2 & test1 == 0 & test2 == 2) {
        return true;
    } else if (number == 3 & test1 == 1 & test2 == 0) {
        return true;
    } else if (number ==5 & test1==1 & test2== 2 & test3== 0){
        return true;
    } else if (test1 ==1 & test2 == 2 & test3 == 0){
        return false;
    } else if (test1 == 1 & test2 == 2) {
        return true;
    } else if (test1 == 1 & test2 == 1 & test3 == 0) {
        return false;
    } else if (test1 == 1 & test2 == 1) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh, I see what you're asking.

Comment: You could just hardcode all valid 32-bit prime numbers. But why?

Comment: no , it's not true , for example try 27 !

Comment: I don't think it's possible without a loop or recursion.  You cannot escape the definition of "prime".  And your approach uses prime #s to determine if a # is prime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No there is no way to perform primality test on an unlimited range of numbers without using any loop. Recursive solutions to this problem are also very limited in that they are not scalable.